# linux csv file concatenate columns into one column

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, cut

I've been looking to do this with sed, awk, or cut. I am willing to use any other command-line program that I can pipe data through.

I have a large set of data that is comma delimited. The rows have between 14 and 20 columns. I need to recursively concatenate column 10 with column 11 per row such that every row has exactly 14 columns. In other words, this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p
```

will become:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
```

I can get the first 10 columns. I can get the last N columns. I can concatenate columns. I cannot think of how to do it in one line so I can pass a stream of endless data through it and end up with exactly 14 columns per row.

Examples (by request):

How many columns are in the row?

```
sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

Get the first 10 columns:

```
cut -d, -f1-10
```

Get the last 4 columns:

```
rev | cut -d, -f1-4 | rev
```

Concatenate columns 10 and 11, showing columns 1-10 after that:

```
awk -F',' ' NF { print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10$11}'
```

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before blindly applying it. I just removed the misapplied "linux" tag.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt imo, tagging `linux` does help for cli solutions.. because GNU versions of `awk/sed/etc` have additional features over POSIX definition..

Comment: Firstly, you can mention that you're using the GNU (not Linux!) version of a tool. Secondly, read the description: It clearly talks about Linux-specific APIs. Many of the GNU programs run on top of other OS kernels, too, they are not Linux-specific.

Comment: yeah, that is one way.. or use the `gnu` tag... but I've seen `linux` tagging as more common in such cases

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     { 
         diff = NF - 14;
         for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
             printf "%s%s", $i, (diff > 1 && i >= 10 && i < (10+diff)?
                                 "": (i == NF? ORS : ",")) 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
```

Answer (score 2):

If `perl` is okay - can be used just like `awk` for stream processing

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4,3,4,3,2,5,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4,a,s,f,e,3,4,3,2,5,2,3,4
$ awk -F, '{print NF}' ip.txt 
16
18
22

$ perl -F, -lane '$n = $#F - 4;
                  print join ",", (@F[0..8], join("", @F[9..$n]), @F[$n+1..$#F])
                 ' ip.txt
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,43432,5,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4asfe3432,5,2,3,4
```

- `-F, -lane` split on `,` results saved in `@F` array
- `$n = $#F - 4` magic number, to ensure output ends with 14 columns. `$#F` gives the index of last element of array (won't work if input line has less than 14 columns)
- `join` helps to stitch array elements together with specified string
- `@F[0..8]` array slice with first 9 elements
- `@F[9..$n]` and `@F[$n+1..$#F]` the other slices as needed

Borrowing from [Ed Morton's regex based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136479)

```
$ perl -F, -lape '$n=$#F-13; s/^([^,]*,){9}\K([^,]*,){$n}/$&=~tr|,||dr/e' ip.txt
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,43432,5,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4asfe3432,5,2,3,4
```

- `$n=$#F-13` magic number
- `^([^,]*,){9}\K` first 9 fields
- `([^,]*,){$n}` fields to change
- `$&=~tr|,||dr` use `tr` to delete the commas
- `e` this modifier allows use of Perl code in replacement section
- this solution also has the added advantage of working even if input field is less than 14

Comment: Perl is great. I haven't used Perl since the late 90s, so I was trying to do it initially with awk, then trying to throw in sed, and even trying cut. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="," }
match($0,"(([^,]+,){9})(([^,]+,){"NF-14"})(.*)",a) {
    $0 = a[1] gensub(/,/,"","g",a[3]) a[5]
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed -E '
s/,/\n/9g
:A
s/([^\n]*\n)(.*)(\n)(([^\n]*\n){4})/\1\2\4/
tA
s/\n/,/g
' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First variant - with awk

```
awk -F, '
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        OFS = (i > 9 && i < NF - 4) ? "" : ","
        if(i == NF) OFS = "\n"
        printf "%s%s", $i, OFS 
    }
}' input.txt
```

#### Second variant - with sed

```
sed -r 's/,/#/10g; :l; s/#(.*)((#[^#]){4})/\1\2/; tl; s/#/,/g' input.txt
```

or, more straightforwardly (without loop) and probably faster.

```
sed -r 's/,(.),(.),(.),(.)$/#\1#\2#\3#\4/; s/,//10g; s/#/,/g' input.txt
```

---

#### Testing

**Input**

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u
```

**Output**

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jklmn,o,p,q,r
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jklmnopq,r,s,t,u
```

Comment: In your 2nd solution you should replace `#` with `\n` since it's GNU-only already and then it'd work even if the input contained `#`s.

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar problem using [csvtool](https://github.com/janloeffler/csvtool). Source file, copied from one of the other answers:

```
$ cat input.txt
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4,3,4,3,2,5,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4,a,s,f,e,3,4,3,2,5,2,3,4
```

Concatenating columns:

```
$ cat input.txt | csvtool format '%1,%2,%3,%4,%5,%6,%7,%8,%9,%10%11%12,%13,%14,%15,%16,%17,%18,%19,%20,%21,%22\n' -
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,jkl,m,n,o,p,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,434,3,2,5,2,3,4,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,4as,f,e,3,4,3,2,5,2,3,4
anatoly@anatoly-workstation:cbs$ cat input.txt
```